# Getting a listview to switch between various arrays for display

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have multiple String arrays in my program (of which i have made individual adapters) on the click of a button i would like to make the listview refresh and display contents from one array (and hence switch to displaying contents of other arrays)

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems from your question you have defined adapter for each string array, so when you want to refresh list view to load other string array just, set adapter for new string array, and your listview get updated automatically.

Like if you have String arrays to load data are:

```
String[][] array=new String[][]={{"a","b","c"}, {"x", "y","z"}, {"1", "2", "3"}};
```

Declare a temp String array to contain data source. say dataSource[].

In onCreate method of activity assign first array to datasource, by:

```
dataSource=array[0];
```

Declare your adapter as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataSource);
```

set This adapter to listView.

in onClick method of button change data source by:

```
dataSource=array[1];//or other array, to which you want to set as new datasource
```

and then call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if all you need to same with with different array, you can do just by having some temp array and set this array as data source of adapter, change this, on button click assign new data source to temp array, and invoke notifyDataSetChanged method on adapter

Comment: how do i change datasource of an adapter. i googled a lot..no solution to that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler to refresh view. Inside method handleMessage() of Class Handler you write the code to refresh the List view. Have a look of this example :http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change adapters at runtime, I think you are looking for this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setAdapter(newAdapter);
```

Comment: i need to link my listview to the one created in the xml.. how will getListView() work?

Comment: getListView will get the listView defined in the xml with id android:id="@android:id/list"